# ArrayFire Segmented Scan / Scatter

Tags: arrayfire

I am trying to achieve the following in ArrayFire:

Inputs:

```
Indices: [  0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   2,   2]
Values : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
```

Output:

```
Result:  [1.0 + 2.0, 3.0 + 1.0 + 2.0, 3.0 + 5.0] = [3.0, 6.0, 8.0]
```

So element `i` in the output is the sum of all the input values whose corresponding index is `i`.

TensorFlow has a scatter_add operation which can be used to do this, but I can't find anything in the ArrayFire docs which seems to fit the bill.  The ArrayFire scanByKey function gets halfway to what I need, and would give the cumulative scan output:

```
[1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 8.0]
```

But I still have to extract just the maximum value for each index (positions 1, 4 and 6) to give me the array I need for the next step, and again I can't find a function to do that.

How can I achieve this using ArrayFire?

Comment: Did you find a solution?